# c# console how to print percent or dimension file or dimension of downloading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, get, console

c# how to print percent or dimension file or dimension of downloading in this method

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(Console.ReadLine());
        // Specify that the DownloadFileCallback method gets called
        // when the download completes.
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCallback);
        // Specify a progress notification handler.
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "temp.mp4");
        Console.WriteLine("Finish");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

while it is running.
I want print in my console in real time the dimension file and percent to finish

with this method I can print the percentage while the file is being downloaded, but the main meanwhile continues to run. How do I block the console until the download finishes?

Comment: Could something like this be something for your solution: [WebClient.DownloadProgressChangedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: no, this is for back-background, but i dont want that program continue a process while is download, i just wnat a print a percent while file is dowloading

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the event:

```
client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
};
```

Comment: so i need to print in a console download percent for print in the console while it is running